# Facebook login setup for android

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-authentication

I face this issue when I setup Facebook login for android. One or more invalid package name(s). Make sure package names are associated with a valid Google Play store URL

I provide the application the proper package name when I'm developing it. Can someone please provide solution how to fix it?